# Take max of non missing date

Tags: python, date, pandas, types, null

I have a Pandas DataFrame with nan and date values (mix of float and datetime):

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [np.nan, 
                         datetime.date(2016, 1, 2), 
                         np.nan], 
                   "B": [datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), 
                         np.nan, 
                         datetime.date(2016, 1, 3)]
                   })
```

I want to take the maximum date across each row.  However, if I take `df.max(axis=1)` I get this:

```
Out[77]: 
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
dtype: float64
```

How can I return the maximum non-null date in each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need convert both columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) first, because mixed values - `dates` and `nan`. Then `nan` are converted to `NaT`

```
df.A = pd.to_datetime(df.A)
df.B = pd.to_datetime(df.B)
print (df)
           A          B
0        NaT 2016-01-01
1 2016-01-02        NaT
2        NaT 2016-01-03

print (df.max())

A   2016-01-02
B   2016-01-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (df.max(axis=1))
0   2016-01-01
1   2016-01-02
2   2016-01-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

More dynamic solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and `list comprehension`:

```
df[['A','B','C']] = pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(df[col]) for col in df[['A','B','C']]], axis=1)
print (df)
           A          B
0        NaT 2016-01-01
1 2016-01-02        NaT
2        NaT 2016-01-03
```

Or use `apply`:

```
df[['A','B','C']] = df[['A','B','C']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

**Timings**:

```
In [28]: %timeit (c(df2))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.55 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit (b(df1))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit (a(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [np.nan, 
                         datetime.date(2016, 1, 2), 
                         np.nan], 
                   "B": [datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), 
                         np.nan, 
                         datetime.date(2016, 1, 3)],
                     "C": [datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), 
                     np.nan, 
                     datetime.date(2016, 1, 3)]
                   })

print (df)
#[300000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

def a(df):
    df[['A','B','C']] = pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(df[col]) for col in df[['A','B','C']]], axis=1)
    return df

def b(df):
    df[['A','B','C']] = df[['A','B','C']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
    return df

def c(df):
    df.A = pd.to_datetime(df.A)
    df.B = pd.to_datetime(df.B)
    df.C = pd.to_datetime(df.C)
    return df
```

Comment: Sweet!  I tried this but didn't apply the `pd.to_datetime` function on each individual column one at a time so it gave me an error.  This works but kind of annoying that I have to loop through the columns.

Comment: Only 3 so this works (will accept answer when time permits) and I set it up to loop so that it can expand but would have preferred to do `pd.to_datetime(df[['A', 'B']])`.

Comment: I add timings, if you have only 3 columns the fastest solution is repeat code 3 times or maybe nicer is use `apply`. If there are more columns, `concat` solution is faster.

Comment: I am still having an issue.  This worked on the example but on my real data it didn't and I'm not sure why.  I am updating the question with some more example output.

Comment: Just updated.  I am guessing it's a date format thing since hours are listed on my true data.  P.S.  I was not the downvoter.

Comment: Ok, but `mean` is not implemented with datetimes. If use sample data, also get all `NaN`

Comment: Ahhhh, ok.  I used `max` and it worked.  Thank you :)